# Reference Decision Split Criteria further along into journey path

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We're populating our Journey table using a file import that overwrites a data extension every day. We utilize contact data via this data extension to split our contacts out into multiple branches via decision splits. Our exit criteria is great for exiting general characteristics (ie: they made a purchase -> exit).

However, once we use data to split our merchants into branches, we know that they will remain in that path based on the criteria they entered into it with. However, we want to send a few weeks of emails after. We know each "wait by duration" will evaluate them based on exit criteria. However, it won't re-evaluate them based on their decision split criteria, correct?

Trying to illustrate this issue, let's pretend we want to offer different promos to different merchants based on purchase date and membership status.

Merchant A has not made a purchase within 30 days and has a gold status.

Day 1 - Merchant A enters the journey
Day 1 - Merchant A enters decision split and is sorted based on purchase_date and memership_status
Day 1 - Merchant A gets Email 1
Day 1 - Merchant A enters 1 week wait by duration period.
** Merchant A goes from "gold status" to "platinum status" within this week period.
Day 8 - Merchant A receives Email 2 (as based on the journey, they still have "gold status").

Ideally, we'd want them to be removed from the journey, and then re-entered as "platinum status" to receive the platinum status offers.

We can use "exit criteria" to remove any merchants who have made a purchase using purchase_date at any wait by duration stage.

HOWEVER, we can't remove merchants based on membership_status because they're simply being treated differently based on their branches.

The only solution I can think to address this, is to create an additional decision split to call back to their data in the data extension. However, that will result in a fairly messy journey buildout.

Is there a better way to call back to the decision split criteria outside of this?

Thank you!